# NDOutils link host-service

Tags: nagios

I would like to know which tables/column allow to link a host with his services in NDOutils?

I need to display a list of some hosts with their own services. I looked but could not find out.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tables `nagios_hosts` and `nagios_services` have a column called `host_object_id`. This is your link.

`SELECT host_object_id FROM nagios_hosts WHERE display_name = 'localhost'`

`SELECT display_name FROM nagios_services WHERE host_object_id = 
   (SELECT host_object_id FROM nagios_hosts WHERE display_name = 'localhost' LIMIT 1)`

Hope this helps.